# Php getting data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have searched multiple tables in database and I am not getting correct answer. This is my code.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('personal_data','personal_data.userid=users.userid','left');
$this->db->join('employed','employed.userid=users.userid','left');
$this->db->join('job_seeker','job_seeker.userid=users.userid','left');
$this->db->join('student','student.userid=users.userid','left');
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

This is the display code.

```
$query=$this->search_people->find_advanced();
foreach ($query as $row) {
    echo $row->userid;
}
```

I think the problem is in query because the output result is not as expected.
Please Help.

UPDATE:
I have 5 tables
1.users. It has the userid as primary key and has fname and lname.
2.personal_data. It has the userid as foreign key. This table contain all the userids of table users And contain the country info and weather the user is employed, job_seeker or student.
3.employed. This table has userid as foreign key. But all the ids of users are not in this table. It contains the info of company etc.
4.job_seeker. This table also has userid as foreign key. All the ids that were in employed are not in job_seeker. It has time period and experience of previous job. etc
5.student. This table also has userid as foreign key. All the ids that were in employed or in job_seeker are not in student. It has the info of School/University, degree and expected completion date.

Now I want to combine all this info in a single table so that i can use it in controller.

I have at the moment 5 users. This query just returns the id of only student table.

But I was expecting the id of all the users.

I hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: `output result is not as expected.` -- well, how are we supposed to know what's the *expected* result?

Comment: There's too much unexplained stuff here. First of all, if the problem is in the query, what is the query? I see the functions used from db but I don't know what they do. You can troubleshoot by outputting the query string generated from your db object. Also, what output result are you getting and as Amal said, what are you supposed to get?

Comment: You're building a multi-branch join structure: users joining individually to 4 separate tables. This is generally NOT a good idea. Joins should be a single linear path, e.g. `a->b->c->d`, not `a->b, a->c, a->d`

Comment: I have the data base. it has 5 tables. I want to get all the data in the all of these tables. I am using userid to combine the data. the userid is unique in users table and in other tables it is the foreign key. I want to display all the data in these tables.

Comment: @Marc This is exactly what i want to do. Could you Please guide me how to do this?

Comment: @SSMA **POST HERE** the resulting SQL query (that You should get after `$this->db->get();`, **POST HERE** what you get now and **POST HERE** what is the expected result. **THANKS**

Comment: @shadyyx The query is the first code. I dont know if it is right or not as i am new to php and mysql. The output is the userid of just student table. But i want the user id of all the tables.

Comment: @MarcB could you please guide me?

Comment: write+run 5 separate queries. that'll be far easier to do and maintain than some ugly query construct that tries to work around the multi-path join problem

Comment: @SSMA "But i want the user id of all the tables." What does that mean? Edit the question and *show us an example of what you want it to look like*, plus *an example of what it looks like now*. There is absolutely no way we can tell you why something you haven't shown us doesn't look like something else you haven't explained to us.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug your code; we cannot do that for you. Find out how to echo the full SQL which was generated, and the full result set returned. Then use a tool like phpMyAdmin to change the SQL and see how it changes the result. Start with simpler code and build up, testing as you go. If you come here every time you get an unexpected result, your development will be a very slow process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please debug query to understand what is happening .
You can use: `$this->db->last_query();` for debugging.
Hope this will help you.